# Stepper motor doesn't move, just vibrates using DRV8428

Tags: pcb, motor, stepper-motor

This is my first time trying to create a stepper motor driver with my own PCB so apologies if I've missed something super obvious.

Anyways, I'm trying to use a DRV8428 ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8428.pdf)) to move a stepper motor with the below schematic. Except when I have connected everything up the motor does not turn and instead I hear it hum and vibrate lightly.

[image: my schematic for the DRV8428]

To try and check it is working I have connected the logic pins to an Arduino and I'm using the following code to send step pulses:

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(N_SLEEP_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENABLE_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(M0_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(M1_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(DIR_PIN, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(STEP_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
  digitalWrite(STEP_PIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
}
```

I made sure to check that the Arduino and driver shared a common ground.

The stepper motor I am using is rated for 12V and 0.35A per per phase.

Using the image below I have tried connecting A and C to AOUT1 and AOUT2 respectively, and B and D to BOUT1 and BOUT2 respectively.

[image: stepper motor configuration]

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: try a much lower step rate, like 10 steps per second

Comment: no luck, you can hear an audible change in the stepper motor when trying different step rates, thank you though

Comment: put first 5 `digitalWrite` in `setup()` just to make sure that those pins are not manipulated at each iteration of `loop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 similar drivers :

- DRV8428 : Step/Dir interface
- DRV8428P: PWM
- DRV8428E: PH/EN

In your schematics, DRV8428PPWPR is refering to DRV8428P.
For STEP/DIR interaface, correct reference is DRV8428PWPR.

Could you check which chip you are testing?

If you are using the DRV8428P, I think you can use the Stepper Arduino library.

Comment: Yep, this was exactly it. I thought I was using the DRV8428PWPR but instead I had the DRV8428PPWPR. Thank you!